# why can't I run two for loops one after another?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

My batch file looks like this

```
for %%K in (apks\*.apk) do apktool -f d %%K -o dist\%%K

for %%A in (apks\*.apk) do echo %%A
```

But when it finishes the first for loop, it doesn't even try to execute the second one. If I remove the first one, the for loop executes fine. Any clues as to why this is happening? I'm new to batch scripting so I thought it might be that I didn't know how to end a line in the file, but I couldn't find anything that would indicate like a semicolon or something at the end of the line.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is `apktool` a batch file? If so, you need to `call` it.

Answer (score -1):

Try it changing "%%" for "%", like this:

```
for %K in (apks\*.apk) do apktool -f d %K -o dist\%K

for %A in (apks\*.apk) do echo %A
```

Comment: The problem was that I needed to `call` apktool. I'm pretty sure you use `%%` when you're writing a .bat file and `%` if you're just running the loop via command line.